# Show task view by swiping the screen (windows 11)

Tags: google-chrome, virtual-desktop

Consider this situation. You are in Google Chrome full screen mode, and you want to open task view. Assume there is no physical keyboard or physical mouse. How can I do this in 1 swipe? Visual basic code. Thx ---sjt.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/touch-gestures-for-windows-a9d28305-4818-a5df-4e2b-e5590f850741#WindowsVersion=Windows_11